# Show that the number of subgroups of finite index n in the group $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is equal to $\sigma(n)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Background: This question comes from chapter 8, Jones number theory, problem 26. The problem is based on the Möbius inversion formula and the Dirichlet product (operator *) is defined as: 
$$\displaystyle(f*g)(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)g(\frac{n}{d})$$
Which is equivalent to(where $e=n/d$): 
$$\displaystyle(f*g)(n)=\sum_{de=n}f(d)g(e)$$
I'm including ex. 8.25 because 8.26 uses 8.25's answer which I also didn't understand.

[image]

Starting with k=2 in 8.25, I don't understand the inductive step explained in the back of the book. Take for example n=6. If you have 
$$\displaystyle(f_1*f_2)(n)=\sum_{de=n}f_1(d)f_2(e)$$
This sum is equivalent to $f_1(1)f_2(6)+f_1(2)f_2(3)+f_1(3)f_2(2)+f_1(6)f_2(1)$
 Now if you apply **inductively** on to this set the only divisor you can add to each element is 1 and you get
$f_1(1)f_2(6)f_3(1)+f_1(2)f_2(3)f_3(1)+f_1(3)f_2(2)f_3(1)+f_1(6)f_2(1)f_3(1)$
The same is true even if the prime factorization of n includes more than two elements. 
Here is the proof:
[image]

But that's not as important as the next question because I understand the conclusion of the last question.

Cheating and looking straight at the answer in the back was not enlightening. If someone could perhaps tell me what the values of a row would be in a miniature example corresponding to $A=\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & d \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ I might understand atleast the question.
Answer:
[image]

Referring to the above answer, they state that the determinant is equal to the index n, therefore we are taking only the highest powers of each prime $p^\alpha\mid\mid n$ and excluding n. In the above example the matrix shows no holes along the diagonal filled in by 1, which doesn't make sense unless $n=p!$ which still should have holes for lower exponents of primes dividing n.  Could someone help?